# removing rows with specific values

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to remove rows that have specific values in a given column

```
id     x_col
1       c4_2342
1       c4_2122 
2       c3_1212
2       c39990
```

I want to remove everything that has "c4"

```
id     x_col
2       c3_1212
2       c39990
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variation on @akrun:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
   filter(!str_detect(x_col, "c4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

For subsetting rows, use `filter` in `dplyr` with a logical expression created by checking for 'c4' substring in the 'x_col' with `str_detect` and use `negate = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(str_detect(x_col, "c4", negate = TRUE))
```

-output

```
id   x_col
1  2 c3_1212
2  2  c39990
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df1, !grepl("c4", x_col))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), x_col = c("c4_2342", "c4_2122", 
"c3_1212", "c39990")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `grep` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'id     x_col
1       c4_2342
1       c4_2122 
2       c3_1212
2       c39990', header = TRUE)

df[- grep("c4", df$x_col),]
#>   id   x_col
#> 3  2 c3_1212
#> 4  2  c39990
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>